# Dialog Window shall open when App launches first time

Tags: java, android

I created a Dialog, that opens each time the App is opened by the user. Since this could annoy the user very fast, I want to open it the first time app is launched and only then.

I tried following:

```
public boolean openDialog = true;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (openDialog) {
        launchDialog();
    }
}

private void launchDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    //don't open Dialog by next launch
                    openDialog = false;

                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Thanks for Help

Adrian

Comment: Your question does not make it clear what it is that you are having trouble with.  What exactly is it that is not working the way you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple sharedPreferences:

```
 private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
 private Editor mEditor;
```

initializing:

```
 mPrefs  = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
```

then when the dialog appeared the first time, save the state for example:

```
mEditor.putBoolean(FIRST_TIME_USED_KEY,true);
mEditor.commit();
```

And when the app will be opened again, ask first if the dialog has opened before:

```
boolean isUsedBefore = mPrefs.getBoolean(FIRST_TIME_USED_KEY,false);

 if(isUsedBefore==true){
   //do nothing
 }else{
  dialog.show();
  }
```

The FIRST_TIME_USED_KEY should be a String stored in strings.xml .

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to achieve this.

**Method 1:**
`Use of shared preference` whenever user open the first time set the status in shared preference and check every time that is need to show the dialog or not.

Note: @Opiatefuchs mention the same thing.

**Method 2:**

`Use database`. For the first time and update the status. For next time check database if the dialog needs to show or not.

Basically both methods are working in a similar way. Choose your best.

Answer (score 0):

make openDialog variables as static to be on the scope of the class not the instances:

```
public static boolean openDialog = true;
```

For best user experience you can show the dialog :

**1.** every time interval (ex:2days).
**2.** every number of runs of the app as (every 5 times).

You can make combination of these two factors , you can do that by saving some values in preferences using the [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)  class.